# Pointer Application using C

Tags: c

Objective: Using only pointer notation, write a function to rotate all values in a list of characters to the left (toward the beginning) by one element.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rotateLeft( char word[] );

int main (void)
{
//  Local Definitions
    char word[20] = "applications";
//  Statements
    printf( "Before rotation: %s\n", word );
    rotateLeft( word );
    printf( " After rotation: %s\n", word );
    return 0;
}

/*  =================================================================== */
/*  Rotate left
    PRE: word[]
    POST: word rotated left
*/
void rotateLeft( char word[] )
{
    char hold;
    char *pW;
    pW = word;
    hold = *pW;

    while (*pW != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c ", *pW);
        *pW = *(pW + 1);
        *pW++;
    }

    *(pW - 1) = hold;
    *pW = '\0';

    return;
}
```

My instructor have told me using *(pW + 1) is a very ugly style. I was wondering if there's an alternative way to solving this solution without using the style that I am current using.

Comment: This doesn't really help you (so I'm not making it an answer), but your instructor is wrong. `*(pW + 1)` is perfectly acceptable C.

Answer (score 4):

`*(pW + 1)` is the same as `pW[1]`.  I don't know about 'very ugly', though.  In fact, in some cases, it's probably preferred.  In fact, you said at the beginning of your question that you're supposed to only use pointer notation, anyway.  Maybe your instructor just didn't like the name `pW`?  You don't need it - since you don't need `word` for anything else, you could just replace all the references to `pW` in your program with `word`.

You should note that in your program, `*pW++` doesn't do anything different than `pW++`, though.  Compiling your program with clang gives this handy warning:

```
example.c:35:13: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
            *pW++;
            ^~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

You also don't need the `*pW = '\0'` line.  Since you didn't modify the existing null terminator, that statement just overwrites a `\0` with a `\0`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I really appreciate it. I've fixed all the errors in my program and it ran correctly. I will show my instructor tomorrow and hope that she approves.